# How to access array elements in foreach loop in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have created a custom array to store questions and the answers but whenever i try to access those array elements it is giving me `attempt to read property "question" on array (`

Actually, i have created a custom array. when i try to create without a custom array it works fine. Like fetching data from the direct eloquent model works fine

This is my JSON response...
[image: response]

```
 @foreach ($questionsArray as $i => $data)
                              <div class=" p-3 m-1 text-left">
                                <p class="font-weight-bold">Q.{{$i + 1}} {{$data->question}}</p>
                              // error is here !
                              
                              @endforeach
```

```
 $questionsArray = array();

        foreach ($questions as $question) {

            $answers = tbl_answer::where('answer_question_table_id', $question->question_id)->get();
            $questionsArray[] = array(
                "question" => array($question),
                "answers"  => array($answers)
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assoc arrays and objects are not the same thing in php.

Here you are making pushing an array with keys `question` and `answers` into `questionsArray`:

```
$questionsArray[] = array(
                "question" => array($question),
                "answers"  => array($answers)
            );
```

So you should read it using array access. assuming `$data` is an element of `$questionsArray` you will have `{{ $data['question'] }}` instead of `{{ $data->question }}`

of course you have wraped some question entity or assoc array inside another array and put it into `$data['question`]` so printing out won't work.

Maybe try something like this:

```
$questionsArray[] = [
                "question" => $question,
                "answers"  => $answers
            ];
```

and then in your blade file read attributes of the question:

```
@foreach ($questionsArray as $i => $data)

    <div class=" p-3 m-1 text-left">
    <p class="font-weight-bold">Q.{{$i + 1}} {{$data['question']['question_title']}}</p>
                              
@endforeach
```